# converting string to date format in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, date, date-formatting

I'm trying to convert a string object that is formatted in a date format (i.e. 2013-12-14 10:00:00.0) and is passed to the `jsp` as such, into another date format (i.e. 12/14/13 10:00:00 AM) on the jsp. I've tried the following lines of code trying to parse the string "date" (which happens to be in a certain date format) to an actual date format:

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${row.date}" type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S" var="formatedDate"/>   
<td class="dataField"><fmt:formatDate value="${formatedDate}"  type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"/></td>
```

But I'm getting the following exception in my console:

> 16:14:01,265 ERROR [[springapp]] Servlet.service() for servlet
>   springapp threw exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "2013-12-14 10:00:00.0"
>           at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)

Does anyone have a better idea why this is not working?

Comment: The `.0` at the end is not in your parsing pattern.

Comment: That's correct: you want to add a `.S` at the end of your `pattern`.

Comment: edited my question, having the pattern there still gave me the same error

Comment: I have tried this way.It's working fine. <fmt:parseDate value="2013-12-14 10:00:00.0" type="date"
  pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S" var="formatedDate" />
 <fmt:formatDate value="${formatedDate}"
   type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a" />

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your time: `10:00:00.0`
You have milliseconds also. To parse such dates you should change your pattern to be `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S`

More reading [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: I've updated the description, the code still doesnt work when i had that format..

Comment: Can't be. This block of code works perfectly: `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S").parse("2013-12-14 10:00:00.0")`

Result: Sat Dec 14 10:00:00 EET 2013

Answer (score 2):

I tried same code, the problem was in format date you should use HH instead of hh

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${row.date}" type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S" var="formatedDate"/>
<td class="dataField"><fmt:formatDate value="${formatedDate}"  type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"/></td>
```